# Extracting building footprint from OSM or Satellite imagery using QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, 3d, feature-extraction, building-heights

I am trying to extract the building footprints from satellite imagery or from OSM using QGIS.

In ArcGIS it is a straightforward task however, I don't know how to do it in QGIS. I need to recognize the buildings so the next step is to make these buildings' footprints 3D shapes that I can save and export to a 3D Prediction SW.

Is there any plug-in or a tool in QGIS that does the job?

Comment: Can you explain the steps you would use in ArcGIS to see if there's QGIS equivalents.

Comment: Extracting building footprints from satellite imagery or from OSM are two totally different thing (from OSM you query a database to get polygons, from satellite imagery you are using image segmentation to generate polygons). You should choose witch way you want to go  (or ask two separate question if you want to assess the feasibility of each method)

Answer (score 3):

You can download buildings as polygons from [OpenStreetMap (OSM)](https://www.openstreetmap.org) - worldwide. Use e.g. [Quick OSM plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickOSM) (screenshot 1).

If you have an attribute for the hight of the building, you can use this to get 3D rendering of the polygon. Some OSM buildings already contain an attribute value for `building:levels`. Use this in `3D View` of `Layer Styling` (or create a new field and and height-values), where you can set this attribute for `Extrusion`. Then open `Menu View / New 3D Map View`: the buildings that contain a value for the `building:levels` attribute are now shown in 3D (see screenshot 2).

Another option would be to combine the polygons with a [Digital Surface Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_elevation_model) (high resolution, best get [LIDAR](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/LIDAR) data) to get the 3D shapes of the buildings from there.

*Screenshot 1: downloaded building polygons from OSM with QuickOSM `Key=building`:*
[image]

*Screenshot 2: 3D extrusion of buildings, based on OSM attribute `building:levels`:*
[image]